# Update attribute "timestamp" reserved word

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I need to update the timestamp attribute in my dynamodb table using boto3 but the attribute name "timestamp" is a reserved word so it's throwing an error on the SET command.

```py
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'id': item_id
    },
    UpdateExpression='SET timestamp = :val1', # this is the line giving the problem
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ":val1": new_timestamp
    }
)
```

"errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: timestamp",

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You can work around this problem using [expression attribute names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html) (similar to the ExpressionAttributeValues you are already using).

```
table.update_item(
  Key={
    'id': item_id
  },
  UpdateExpression='SET #ts = :val1',
  ExpressionAttributeValues={
    ":val1": new_timestamp
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames={
    "#ts": "timestamp"
  }
)
```

Read all about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Was not expecting they treat these as reserved.

Comment: How do we do multiply field updates using this pattern?